# How to pass return passed data back into a component to display in html

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Ok so i have a file which has a bunch of utility functions in a separate file for example:

```js
const imprGuid = () => {
  data.map((result) => {
    return result.request.requestContext.mpcBidRequest.imprGuid;
  });
};
```

I have my main index.js component like so

```
const IndexPage = () => {
  return (
    <Layout>
      <main>
        <section id='request' className={sectionStyles}>
          <h2 className={h2Styles}>request</h2>
          <div className='mt-5 flex justify-around'>
            <Btn onClick={() => imprGuid()}>sspBidFloor</Btn>
            <Btn onClick={() => console.log('button was clicked')}>geoData</Btn>
```

I have a UI of buttons. Which will call the ultil functions separately onClick. Once the function is called i want to display the result within the UI, however I cant seem to wrap my head around two things.

1. how to display the returned data within the UI. I have already imported it and used it on the `onClick` but how can i display what is returned else where?
2. how can change what is display depending on which button is clicked...for example, i click one button to display something i click another button i want to replace previous with new.

Update:

I have added `useState` but the returned value still isnt showing up.

```
const IndexPage = () => {
  const [data, setData] = useState();
  ...
```

button click is

```
<Btn onClick={() => setData(imprGuid())}>sspBidFloor</Btn>
```

util function is now:

```
const imprGuid = () => {
  data.map((result) => {
    let imprGuid = result.request.requestContext.mpcBidRequest.imprGuid;
    console.log(imprGuid);
    return imprGuid;
  });
};
```

and I am placing data in the component like {data} but nothing is appearing, but the result prints to the console fine. So I am guessing it would return the data ok?

---

Further Update.

```
{data.map((result, i) => (
            <>
              {i}: {result}
              <br />
            </>
          ))}
```

I am now getting Cannot read property 'map' of undefined. However the fix worked and then i refreshed and now it's returning undefined... the state and functions havent changed :(

Comment: Note: `imprGuid` doesn't return anything.

Comment: `onClick` event change the value of a state. Use react state hooks. It will be automatically re-rendered. https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html

Comment: @Andy how comes it doesnt return anything, when i can get the result printed to the console. How can i get it to return the result?

Comment: `map` returns a new array. But that array needs to be returned from the function: `return data.map(result ....`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Andy said, the `imprGuid` function doesn't return anything, that's why it's not working.

The function below should solve your problem :

```
const imprGuid = () => {
  return data.map(result => result.request.requestContext.mpcBidRequest.imprGuid);
};
```

To add a break line between each element, you can use a `<br/>` tag.

```
<code>
  {(data || []).map(el => <>el<br/></>)}
</code>
```

Comment: Thanks @Olivier amazing...now i am populating everything, how can i return everything on a newline? I have tried `<code className='whitespace-pre-wrap'>{data}</code>` but still populates the data across one line...I guess ill have to do something with the returned data in the function over where i am populating?

Comment: @mrpbennett I edited my answer to show you how you can populate data with break lines by using `<br/>` tag

Comment: you bloody legend!! That's a massive help thank you dude!!

Comment: oops spoke too soon...i have edited my question...i am getting data.map is undefined but your fix did work but now it's not... :(

Comment: because you initialize your data with undefined, you can use `const [data, setData] = useState([]);` to solve the problem. Anyway I edited my answer to handle an undefined `data`

Comment: i have this though ... `const IndexPage = () => {
  const [data, setData] = useState();` as which is why i find it odd

Comment: you should use `useState([])`

Comment: perfec that has fixed it...once again thank you dude!